# What are the layers of protection Azure Offers for PAAS and IAAS services for DDOS protection

Tags: security, azure, ddos

I read the documentation of app service security in that they are mention like Azure provide basic functionality from DDOS attacks.

[Infrastructure and platform security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-security?toc=%2Fazure%2Fapp-service%2Ftoc.json)

What are the layers of protection Azure Offers for PAAS and IAAS services for DDOS protection ?

Answer (score 1):

Azure offers DDoS protection on the platform level. It defends against attacks on its infrastructure. That means that incoming traffic is analyzed and, if classified as a DDoS attack, it is blocked. Microsoft does not disclose how this is done exactly.

This does not mean you can rely solely on this for protection of your application, because what may be a little traffic for an Azure datacenter may be a full blown DDoS on your application.

The [Azure security best practices document](http://download.microsoft.com/documents/uk/enterprise/88_Security_Best_Practices_For_Developing_Windows_Azure_Applicat.pdf) says this:

> Windows Azure‟s load balancing will partially mitigate Denial of Service attacks from the Internet and internal networks. This mitigation is done in conjunction with the developer defining an appropriate Service Definition VM instance count scale-out. On the Internet, Windows Azure VMs are only accessible through public Virtual IP Addresses (VIPs). VIP traffic is routed through Windows Azure‟s load-balancing infrastructure. Windows Azure monitors and detects internally initiated Denial of Service attacks and removes offending VMs/accounts from the network. As a further protection, the root host OS that controls guest VMs in the cloud is not directly addressable internally by other tenants on the Windows Azure network and the root host OS is not externally addressable.

This document is a bit dated, but I think the principle still applies.